# Understanding the program sequence when using for (;clock() - now < CLOCKS_PER_SEC;)

Tags: c, linux

Hie guys I am a beginner C programmer and while I was programming a simple terminal watch I noticed there was a problem with the sequence of execution of my code: instead of displaying the time when I run the program, first the cursor blinks for about 3 seconds and then the time is displayed. Here is my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 10

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    time_t t;
    size_t sz;
    clock_t now;
    struct tm* tm;
    static char strtm[BUFSIZE];

    while (1)
    {
        now = clock();
        t = time(NULL);
        tm = gmtime(&t);

        sz = strftime(strtm, sizeof(strtm), "%T", tm);

        #if 1 
        for (;(clock() - now) < (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/3);)
            printf("\r");
        #endif

        printf("%s", strtm);
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

So to test the program sequence I wrote the following simple code and it behaves in a similar way. What I want the following code to do is

1. Display "1 2 3 4",
2. Move the cursor to the '1',
3. wait for about 5 second and then exit

However, instead of doing that it first waits for 5 seconds before displaying "1 2 3 4"

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    clock_t now = clock();

    printf("1 2 3 4");

    printf("\r");

    for (;(clock() - now) < (5 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);)
    ;

    return 0;
}
```

I am working on linux so I tried using the `sleep()` function and I got the same result:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    printf("1 2 3 4");

    printf("\r");

    sleep(5);

    return 0;
}
```

I need you to help me understand the sequence of my program because it seems to be running the for `loop / sleep()` function first before the `printf()`. Corrections are very welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely just seeing the effect of output buffering. Note that `'\r'` does not typically flush the output buffer, unlike `'\n'`. So use [fflush()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) to enforce the required behaviour, e.g.

```
printf("1 2 3 4");
printf("\r");
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul R I tried your answer on the all the programs and they are now okay